# bootstrap css - how to make a modal dialog modal without affecting the background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap css, it is possible to display a modal dialog, but I want to be able to make it modal so the UI behind doesn't respond, without having the dark black background shown.

There seems to be no options that allow me to do this on the $("#selector").modal() function.

Comment: Please could you post the relevant code as jsfiddle.net for us to see and play with?  It'll literally take a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NUVrd/1/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get rid of the backdrop:

After modal initiation

`$('#XXX').modal({show:true});`

just trigger the code below

```
 $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass("modal-backdrop");
```

Comment: Look at the answer below by Alex Marple for the **correct** approach.

Comment: @FastTrack Thanks for the heads up, SO should change how they sort answers. Too many times the best solution is buried on popular questions.

Comment: This will make the backdrop disappear but the elements behind it are not clickable.

Answer (score 192):

add `data-backdrop="false"` to `<div class="modal">` and Bootstrap will do the rest.

Example:

```
<div class="modal" id="genericModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer. Should have been the approved one.

Comment: This solution affects the background. Not what you see, but what you click.

Comment: In bootstrap 5 the attribute is data-bs-backdrop

Answer (score 20):

The correct way is to pass the param `backdrop: false` when create the modal

```
$('#modal').modal({
  backdrop: false
})
```

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to just hide the backdrop so that you still have that feature of clicking out of the modal to hide it.

```
.modal-backdrop { opacity: 0 !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

In bootstrap 5 the attribute is `data-bs-backdrop`.

Example:

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="false">
```

Answer (score 2):

if I'm correct you should be able to do this by calling:

```
$("#selector").modal({
    backdrop: "static"
});
```

then just change the CSS for the class of the backdrop and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Surey all you need to do is tweak the CSS to change the opacity of the black background. It doesn't have to be visible to block clicks to underlying elements (unless there's some clickjacking protection I don't know about?). The class to target is div.modal-backdrop.

Comment: I just tested this and after setting opacity: 0 on that element, it still intercepts clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the css style as

```
 .modal-backdrop {background: none;}
 .modal{background: none;}
```

And all your modal background will go away for every modal you want to display in your app.