# bootstrap 3.3.2: how to show modal without modifying the background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to show a modal but not to black out the background image.
I was able to get some progress by changing the opacity of .modal-backdrop to 0 but still the background image got some grey layer.

Does anyone know how to keep the background image intact?

Thanks

Comment: You can remove it like this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30946769/971675)

Comment: I did set data-backdrop="false", not I see some light grey
Is it possible to remove it completely?

Comment: I had some custom css rules I had to take out.
it works